# Error running Vorto Dashboard for Bosch iot suite

Tags: node.js, npm, oauth2client, bosch-iot-suite, eclipse-vorto

I am trying to run Vorto dashboard on Raspberry Pi to visualize my Bosch IoT "things" data.

In order to run the Vorto Dashboard, I installed npm and nodejs and created the config.json file.

I am getting the below error whenever I try to run the dashboard using the command: `sudo vorto-dashboard config.json`, knowing that I already added the OAuth2 Client credentials.

> No credentials given, can not get things
>
> Could not get the token with given credentials. `- StatusCodeError: 400 -`
> {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
> Invalid client credentials"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

To resolve your issue, store your OAUth credentials as environmental variables.

E.g. in debian et al., `export BOSCH_CLIENT_ID=...` etc., then start the dashboard in the same terminal.

---

**Context**

I was about to ask the same question, as I got the same error message no matter how I referenced the `config.json` file (relative path, absolute path, no reference, etc.).

For clarification, the tutorial pointing to a `config.json` resource for storing OAuth credentials is [here](https://github.com/eclipse/vorto/blob/master/docs/tutorials/create_webapp_dashboard.md).

Quoting:

> While the dependencies are being installed, create the `config.json` file and insert `client_id`, secret and scope from your Already created
>   OAuth2 Client. The content of the file has to look like this:
>
> `{
>     "client_id": "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>",
>     "client_secret": "<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET", 
>     "scope": "<YOUR_SCOPE>", 
>     "intervalMS": 10000 
>   }`

The reference to the `config.json` file has been removed from the `README.md` resource in the `vorto-dashboard` module of `vorto-examples`.

The latest [README.md](https://github.com/eclipse/vorto-examples/blob/master/vorto-dashboard/README.md) suggests providing the OAuth credentials through environmental variables:

> You can provide your OAuth2 credentials through environment variables.
>   The three environment variables you have to provide are:
>
> `BOSCH_CLIENT_ID`
>
> `BOSCH_CLIENT_SECRET`
>
> `BOSCH_SCOPE`
>
> [...]

Looking at the source, I can only find an explicit reference to a `config.json` in the `start` script entry for [package_for_deployment.json](https://github.com/eclipse/vorto-examples/blob/master/vorto-dashboard/package_for_deployment.json) (nor anything around the source seems to be consuming, say, `argv[2]` for that matter).

The [AuthToken.js](https://github.com/eclipse/vorto-examples/blob/master/vorto-dashboard/things/DataPoller/AuthToken.js) resource in charge of handling OAuth credentials only seems to reference environmental variables through the `process.env.[...]` references.

**Elaboration**

This is only speculation at the time of writing, but I suspect the reason why the `config.json` methodology has been abandoned might have something to do with strengthening security, i.e. not storing OAuth credentials permanently in a file.

If that much is true, then the tutorial [page](https://github.com/eclipse/vorto/blob/master/docs/tutorials/create_webapp_dashboard.md) should probably be amended with the latest instructions from the [README.md](https://github.com/eclipse/vorto-examples/blob/master/vorto-dashboard/README.md).

Comment: Thank you, Mena 
storing the OAuth2 credentials and passing them through environment variables solved the problem.

Comment: Good to hear @MhdEyadAlmolki. Happy prototyping!

Answer (score 1):

I am currently contributing the Vorto Project as an Intern at Bosch. Due to changes in the Vorto-Dashboard we combined and merged the functionality of a previous dashboard with another coexisting updated UI, providing advanced ways to visualize the existing devices.

As the uploaded state was work in progress, we temporarily disabled the `config.json` methodology and removed existing references from the documentation. Apparently, the reference in the [tutorial](https://github.com/eclipse/vorto/blob/master/docs/tutorials/create_webapp_dashboard.md) you found was omitted, sorry for that!

Today, I deployed a new version [0.5.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vorto-dashboard) of the vorto-dashboard which should work as usual. You are now able to work with either `process.env.[...]` varibales or a `config.json` file. Thank you [Mena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2353911/mena) for the quick response!

Feel free to let me know if you need any further help or have additional feedback.

Comment: Thank you
I solved the problem as Mena suggested and the error has been solved
Unfortunately, I am seeing a black dashboard even though I am getting that 2 things have been fetched.

Comment: @MhdEyadAlmolki btw I don't have an immediate solution to your additional issue but if it persists after waiting a while / refreshing the page, you probably want to collect whatever data is available to you (logs etc.) and see if that makes a good additional SO question.