# Vorto Dashboard not displaying the device model

Tags: bosch-iot-suite, eclipse-vorto

while running the vorto dashboard im getting the following error

```
       JWT expired, getting new Token Wed Aug 26 2020 07:38:56 GMT+0100 (BST)... StatusCodeError: 401 - 
{"status":401,"error":"gateway:authentication.failed","message":"Multiple authentication 
mechanisms were applicable but none succeeded.","description":"For a successful authentication
 see the following suggestions: { The JSON Web Token is not valid. }, 
{ Please provide a valid JWT in the authorization header prefixed with 'Bearer ' }."
```

The contents of config.json is as follows

```
{
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "scope": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "intervalMS": 10000
}
```

Tried with setting the contents of config.json as environment variables. Then also im getting same error. Screenshot of web front end on accessing localhost:8080 is attached
[image]

Tried with the following links [Error running Vorto Dashboard for Bosch iot suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487307/error-running-vorto-dashboard-for-bosch-iot-suite). But still its not working. Please help me in solving this issue

Comment: I think this issue has been formalized [here](https://github.com/eclipse/vorto/issues/2565).

Comment: @Mena Yeah.. Waiting for its solution... Is there any workaround for this bug.

Comment: not that I know of so far unfortunately. It looks more like a change on Things' side since the Vorto dashboard is not often maintained and nothing's changed in there for a while.

Comment: Note: by "things" I meant more like Suite Auth since what seems to be broken is the authentication process in use. I'm having a look at what the app does vs the most recent documentation, as soon as I can dig it out...

Comment: I think I have a clue why this is breaking. The token returned by the app's call to `https://access.bosch-iot-suite.com/token` differs from the one you'd get by, e.g. using your OAuth client on `https://accounts.bosch-iot-suite.com/oauth2-clients/`. Chiefly because it does not contain your scopes. That definitely seems to not work with things APIs. I'm going to throw the question around and fish for answers soon.

Comment: @Mena Thankyou for the effort. Expecting to be resolved soon

Answer (score 0):

I have discussed the matter internally to Bosch (disclaimer: I am an employee).

After discussing with the Bosch Suite Auth team, here is a summary of what happened.

- The Suite Auth team recently transitioned from Keycloack to Hydra for their authentication technology
- The relevant bit here is that previously, the scopes passed to the token request were ignored
- The Vorto Dashboard app had been passing the wrong key for the scope parameter all along, when requesting a token, but it was ignored
- Now that this parameter is relevant, the (incorrect) notation was not failing to produce a token, but obtained one that was not suitable to authorize with Bosch IoT Things, because it did not contain the appropriate scope
- In turn, fixing this key produces a token that successfully authorizes with Bosch IoT Things

---

If you're in a hurry, you can check out [this](https://github.com/eclipse/vorto-examples/tree/2565) branch with the fix (it's literally an 8 characters change set).

Otherwise, you can monitor [this](https://github.com/eclipse/vorto/issues/2565) GitHub ticket for closure - I will close it when the fix is merged to the master branch of the Vorto Examples project.

Comment: Now merged to the master branch.